# obfuscate js using cli

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use [javascript-obfuscator](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator) package, it works fine if I do operations with files, like:

`javascript-obfuscator source.js`

but I need to dynamically change js source content and get output on console in way like

`javascript-obfuscator "var foo = 'bar'; alert(foo);"`

Any suggestion how can I get rid from saving content to file and do it like in snippet above?

Comment: "_I need to dynamically change js source content_" sounds like bad design ...

Comment: I mean, does what you wrote not work? Do you need to pipe the output to the stdout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really considering *why* you'd need to do this, it looks like you'll need to use the programmatic API as described in the library's README.

Let's call this `obfuscate.js`:

```
var JavaScriptObfuscator = require('javascript-obfuscator');
var obfuscationResult = JavaScriptObfuscator.obfuscate(
    process.argv[2],
    {
        compact: false,
        controlFlowFlattening: true
    }
);

console.log(obfuscationResult.getObfuscatedCode());
```

`$ node obfuscate.js 'console.log(1)'`

will then output (for example)

```
var _0x2b5a = ['log'];
(function (_0x630038, _0x2944a9) {
    var _0x83df37 = function (_0x2ef1a5) {
        while (--_0x2ef1a5) {
            _0x630038['push'](_0x630038['shift']());
        }
    };
    _0x83df37(++_0x2944a9);
}(_0x2b5a, 0xd7));
var _0x493b = function (_0x2b48eb, _0x33884a) {
    _0x2b48eb = _0x2b48eb - 0x0;
    var _0x41338b = _0x2b5a[_0x2b48eb];
    return _0x41338b;
};
console[_0x493b('0x0')](0x1);
```